# Prevent Users from copying and pasting or no?

Tags: html, keyboard, textarea

To prevent the use of spam I am considering disabling the use of `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v` and any other copy/paste keybindings on registrating and messaging forms. Is this a good idea? I know people may be agitated by the denial of common keyboarding logic, but would it still be worth implementing?

Comment: It would depend on what you're trying to achieve. if you need it, go for it.

Comment: It would frustrate me. I'd probably go out of my way to copy that information out of the source. Most users probably would just deal with it though.